# Помогите разобраться в пошаговой логике

Tags: javascript

Задание: Перебери объект apartment используя цикл for...in и запиши в массив keys все его ключи, а в массив values все значения его свойств.

Задача:

```
const apartment = {
  descr: "Spacious apartment in the city center",
  rating: 4,
  price: 2153,
};
const keys = [];
const values = [];
// Change code below this line
```

ВОПРОС: как записать в массив ключи и свойства? Не понимаю для чего в условии даны переменные ?

```
const keys = [];
const values = [];
```

Мы же можем прописать `for in`, затем использовать `Object.keys`/`Object.values`?

Comment: "Мы же можем  использовать Object.keys/Object.values" --- можете, но просят вас сделать именно через **for...in** и это намеренно .............."зачем даны переменные const keys = []; const values = []"  --- чтобы вы выполнили условие задачи, которое у вас в самом начале описано русским чётким языком........... что тут объяснять не ясно, если у вас конкретно всё написано что надо сделать и что использовать

Comment: Я понимаю, что необходимо перебрать объект и записать результат в массив.  const apartment = {
  descr: "Spacious apartment in the city center",
  rating: 4,
  price: 2153,
};
const keys = [];
const values = [];
// Change code below this line
for (const key in keys) {
  console.log(apartment[key])
}

Comment: ну иииии? так вопрос тогда в чём?

Comment: Не получается вывести в сам массив. Что я не так делаю?)

Comment: метод "запихивания" в массив - push - https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Comment: в итоге в один пихаются key, в другой - keys[key]

Comment: я логику общую понимаю, но прописать не получается и получить результат(

Comment: ну напиши как получается.....что там понимать.....у тебя **уже всё есть**... цикл есть...ключи и значения есть.....переменные массивые есть....  то, что надо применить метод push - написал........всё.........что ещё надо для жизни.

Answer (score 1):

```
const apartment = {
  descr: "Spacious apartment in the city center",
  rating: 4,
  price: 2153,
};
const keys = [];
const values = [];
// Change code below this line
for(const key in apartment){
  keys.push(key)
  values.push(apartment[key])
}
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
const keys = [];
const values = [];
const advert = {
  service: "apt",
};
const apartment = Object.create(advert);
apartment.descr = "Spacious apartment in the city center";
apartment.rating = 4;
apartment.price = 2153;

for (const key in apartment) {
if (apartment.hasOwnProperty(key)){
  keys.push(key);
  values.push(apartment[key]);
}
}
```